# How to find all the regular subgroups of a permutation group of a non abelian group normalised by the left regular representation

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, hopf-algebras

Given a finite non abelian group $G$, and it's permutation group $Perm(G)$ how would I go about finding all of the regular subgroups $N$ of $Perm(G)$?

I'm looking at applying the theorem of Greither and Pareigis in Hopf-Galois theory, which states that given a Galois extension $L/K$, with Galois group $G$, there is a bijection between the regular subgroups of $Perm(G)$ normalised by the left regular representation $\lambda$ and the $K$-Hopf Galois structures on $L/K$.

Once the regular subgroups are found, is it then just a case of checking which of these are normalised by $\lambda$ or is there a trick to speed things up a bit?

For example, if $G=\cal{Q}_8$, the group of quaternions, I have seen a paper (http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2019/25-13v.pdf) that states that there are a certain number of such groups $N$, and it then goes on to explicitly calculate what each group looks like and shows it is regular. The paper doesn't make mention of why this list is exhaustive and how one would go about finding these subgroups in the first place.

I understand that it is a non-trivial undertaking, but I was hoping that there is some tactical approach instead of sheer brute force calculations in each case.

Comment: Chasing the reference you posted, $Perm(G)$ seems to be what many would call $Sym(G)$, the symmetric group on $G$. (The group of all permutations of the underlying set of $G$.) But the regular subgroups of a finite symmetric group are fairly well-understood: in $Sym(n)$, there is one conjugacy class of regular subgroup for each isomorphism type of groups of order $n$ and the size of the class is $\frac{n!}{n|A|}$, where $A$ is the automorphism group of a representative. The fact that you are interested in $Sym(G)$ instead of $Sym(n)$ makes essentially no difference.

Comment: So, to take your example of $G=Q_8$, there are five conjugacy classes of regular subgroups in $Sym(G)$,  and their sizes are $30$, $210$, $630$, $630$ and $1260$. This computation is very easy using the above, and we could carry this out as far as we have an enumeration of all groups of order $|G|$. This calculation does not seem to match anything in the paper you link, so I suspect you the question you posted might not have been exactly what you had in mind.

Comment: Isn't $Sym(G)\subseteq Sym(n)$ where $n=\mid G\mid$? Since there are some further relations that hold for the 8 elements of $G$ that essentially result in the equality of some elements of $Sym(n)$ when applied to $G$?

Comment: $Sym(G)$ by definition is the set of permutation of the underlying set of $G$. There are $|G|!$ such permutation, so we have equality. There is nothing in the definition about preserving relations of any kind. Perhaps you are thinking of $Aut(G)$ (the group of automorphisms?), rather than $Sym(G)$?